# Php read directory with absolute path

Tags: php, directory

I have this php script which reads mp3 files from the directory:

```
// Set your return content type
header('Content-type: text/xml');

//directory to read
$dir = ($_REQUEST['dir']);
$sub_dirs = isBoolean(($_REQUEST['sub_dirs']));

if(file_exists($dir)==false){
    //echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    //echo "current working directory is -> ". getcwd();
    echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
}else{
    $temp = getFileList($dir, $sub_dirs);
    echo json_encode($temp);
}

function isBoolean($value) {
   if ($value && strtolower($value) !== "false") {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}

function getFileList($dir, $recurse){ 

    $retval = array(); // array to hold return value 
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") // add trailing slash if missing 
    $dir .= "/"; // open pointer to directory and read list of files 
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading"); 

    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) { // skip hidden files
        if($entry[0] == "." || $entry[0] == "..") continue; 

        if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) { 
            if($recurse && is_readable("$dir$entry/")) { 
                $retval = array_merge($retval, getFileList("$dir$entry/", true)); 
            }
        }else if(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
            $path_info = pathinfo("$dir$entry");
            if(strtolower($path_info['extension'])=='mp3'){
                $retval[] = array( 
                    "path" => "$dir$entry", 
                    "type" => $path_info['extension'],
                    "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"), 
                    "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry") 
                ); 
            }
        } 
    } 
    $d->close();
    return $retval; 
}
```

This file sits in the same directory as the html page which executes the script. For example, I pass the relative path `'audio/mp3' or '../audio/mp3'` and it all works well.

Is it possible to make this read directory with absolute path?

For example, if I would pass this: http://www.mydomain.com/someFolder/audio/mp3, and html page which executes the script and the php file would be placed in this location: http://www.mydomain.com/someFolder/

Thank you!

Comment: ...have you, say, tried running it using an absolute path?

Comment: Use [directoryiterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) instead and maybe this is not a good idea to allow someone to read your file system.

Answer (score 0):

Web root is always just /. You'd never need the hostname or protocol part, and root can be only root of the server, not some folder or file.

If you need some path, like /testthesis/ - there are ways, but it has nothing common with web root.

If you need a filesystem directory for the webroot - it's in the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable.